# How do you access the faces of a model in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm working on collision detection for a game written using the Microsoft XNA framework version 4.0. When trying to access the model itself once it's been loaded by the content framework, I can access a list of "ModelMesh"es, and for each one a list of MeshParts, but the parts only seem to have diagnostic data like the number of vertices. I'm completely stumped as to what's happened to the actual face data for the model.

I'm trying to implement sphere-sweep/plane collision-- that is, I have a ball moving and I'd like to test collision with a polygon as the ball moves. I need a way to define all the polygons to test with, and it just makes sense to me to define a collision map as a simplified mesh that I design in parallel with my actual graphics object to use for the colliding, but I'm completely baffled as to how I'm supposed to access that info once XNA's content pipeline has loaded it.

Some insight here perhaps? I've been combing Google all day and I'm unable to locate anything that might help, although it's possible that I'm using the wrong search terms...

Comment: Of note: every tutorial I've come across seems to discuss object vs object collision. Since the level is (a) static, and also (b) very easy to subdivide into smaller parts, I figured it would make more sense to do per-polygon collision on it. If there's some other way to do collision that is preferred here feel free to suggest it in the comments, but it doesn't solve the main problem-- how do you get to face data in XNA?

Comment: my answer addresses getting face data, not collision detection. Of course, once you have that, building a BSP or whatever is easy and will handle your collision detection issue.

Comment: also, don't worry about a "simplified model" for collision detection. A BSP will give you (ideally) log-base-2(n) checks for collision detection with a static tree. So, 16 10-20 instruction compares per 64k triangles. It's very, very fast, and will not be your performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in XNA FBX/model content importer and processor handle "faces" the same way that just about every modeling program out there does - as lists of vertices and indices. (As a side note, your GPU also natively supports this scheme, and modern games rely upon it for performance reasons.)

For instance, consider a simple, two-triangle quad. The vertices might be:

```
v0 (0,0,0)
v1 (1,0,0)
v2 (1,1,0)
v3 (0,1,0)
```

or,

```
v0--v1
|  / |
| /  |
v3--v2
```

To represent this in "face" form, you'd need a list of data equivalent to

triangle 1 (upper-left): (0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0) = (v0,v1,v3)

triangle 2 (lower-right): (1,0,0),(1,1,0),(0,1,0) = (v1,v2,v3)

which requires six vertex records.

Using XNA-native structures, a Vector3 has three elements, each of which are single-precision floats (4 bytes), so that's 3*4=12 bytes each, and you need six of them, so that 72 bytes.

Or, you can use indexing. In addition to the four vertices, you store a list of indices:

```
f1: 0,1,3
f2: 1,2,3
```

Indices can be stored using shorts (16-bit integers). So, let's examine the difference:

No indices: two faces * 3 vertices*3 components (xyz) * 4 bytes each = 2*3*3*4=72 bytes.

Indexed:

vertices: 4 vertices * 3 components each * 4 bytes per component = 48 bytes,

indices (3 shorts per triangle): 6 indices * 2 bytes each = 12 bytes.

48 + 12 = 60, which is slightly less than 72 bytes for the non-indexed model.

That 12 bytes might not seem like a lot until you consider an entire level with 100,000+ triangles. At that point, you're looking at a 1.2MB difference. Although your graphics card may about 2+GB of memory, moving that data back and forth between host RAM and GPU RAM is expensive.

So, how do you get that data?

Look at `Model.Meshes[].MeshParts[].VertexBuffer.GetData()` and `Model.Meshes[].MeshParts[].IndexBuffer.GetData()`. You can use those methods to extract the vertices and indexes, then cross-reference the two to get the triangle list.

*You can't just directly access the elements of `VertexBuffer` and `IndexBuffer` because they are stored in the GPU's RAM - allowing random element access would drag performance to near-negative velocity.*

Also, have a look at the `GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives()` method.

I can post some example code later if necessary.

Comment: OK, I follow this for the most part. Are all faces stored as triangles? Like, if I grab the index buffer, can I safely assume that a new face will be defined by every 3 index values, or do I need some way to discover the number of points in a face? (What I mean here is, if I have quads defined in my model, are they automatically being converted to triangles when sent to the graphics card?)

Comment: Everything should be stored as triangles. The GPU doesn't understand quads. When you call a Device.Draw method, you gave to tell it what primitive type you're using. Line list , triangle list or triangle strip. No quads.

Comment: Good! Also check the app hub forums hosted by Microsoft. The XNA devs are very active there.